# Alert is not detected for zoom with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to click on the alert button of Zoom
But I get an error

[image]

I want to click on the 'Open Zoom Meetings' button.
This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  
url = "https://us04web.zoom.us/j/74697911381"
  
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver,5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="zoom-ui-frame"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.alert_is_present())
alert = driver.switch_to.alert()
alert.accept()
```

I got an Error like this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.alert_is_present())
  File "C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: You can't interact with that alert using selenium. Sounds like a job for `autoit`

Comment: @C.Peck : AutoIT is not a generic solution, OP might wanna run their script on linux.

Comment: @Johan Jomy : This is a genuine problem, it does not deserve to be downvoted (+1)